# Changing BackgroundTint of a MaterialButton

Tags: android

I'm using the lasted **support design : 28**, alpha3.

I use using the **"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"** as the theme for my application and "**MaterialButton**" instead of a normal "Button" in my layouts.

I can set the BackgroundTind from the XML as normal but i can't change it via java.

I tried:

```
deliverSwitch.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorYellow));

deliverSwitch.setSupportBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorYellow));
```

but none of them worked... I also tried to clear the current tint by leaving the setBackgroundTintList null and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't get it working either. As a workaround I did the following: First you get the current background Drawable, then you tint it with the desired color and set the new background with setBackgroundDrawable for your Material Button.

```
Drawable background = materialButton.getBackground();
background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.bg_button_primary));
materialButton.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

I hope that helps.